# Is it OK to import Node.js modules to use in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a silly question. I need to create UUID in my Next.js project but I don't want to add redundant package. So in the component I imported `crypto` as this:

```js
import crypto from 'crypto';
```

Then, I have been using as this:

```js
const generateUuid = () => {
  console.log(crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex'))
}

return <button onClick={generateUuid}>Generate UUID</button>
```

It works and therefore I'm nearly confused.

Other articles says that you should use `getInitialProps` to ensure the code is running on the server. But I have no problem. Can you please describe it and make me correct if I'm mistaken?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

next.js has two runtimes. `edge` and `node`. edge runtime supports the `crypto`. [Edge Runtime support those](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/edge)

[From here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-1#a-light-nodejs-runtime-for-the-edge-now-stable-for-api-routes)

> The Edge Runtime inside Next.js uses a strict subset of Node.js APIs
> (like Request, Response, and more) which are compatible with Edge
> computing platforms like Vercel or when self-hosting. These APIs run
> everywhere, including in the browser, allowing developers to learn
> them once and write everywhere.

Vercel has a demo [edge-functions-crypto](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/edge-functions-crypto)